# Google Tag Manager : universal analytics does not track page views with adblock

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, adblock, pageviews

I have created a tag to track page views with universal analytics on google tag manager. Tracking page views does not work when adblock is enabled. Why the page view is not tracked with universal analytics tag in google tag manager ?

What I don't understand is that if I implement the classic google analytics tag the views are tracked with adblock enabled.

I did not find anything relevant on that issue.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: My educated guess would be that you have demographics features enabled, and since this calls the Doubleclick domain Adblock confuses the request with advertising.  I am not sure this is on topic, though.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thanks for your answer. You mean demographics enabled on google tag manager ? When I use the tag classic google analytics it tracks all page views even when there is adblock enabled. However if I use the tag universal analytics then it does not track page views if adblock is enabled.

Comment: Yes. Universal Analytics and "classic" analytics use different libraries and different endpoints, so it is very well possible that one is blocked and one is not. But as I said, this is an (albeit educated) guess.

Comment: @EikePierstorff is rigth, I have the same problem time ago and was that the reason, but unchecking that you remarketing list won't work properly. It's a hard choise.